# Сравнение с несколькими значениями типа string (C#)

Tags: c#, строки

Нужно вывести на экран все цифры из ListBox в Label. Как мне сделать множественную проверку?

```
int index = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
string str = (string)listBox1.Items[index];
int len = str.Length;
int i = 0;
while (i < len)
{
    if (str[i] == //Здесь должны быть несколько вариантов для проверки, как: '1', '2', и т.д.
}
```

Comment: Please, fix your question to russian only text. And give more clear explanation what do you need to do. Пожалуста, уберите весь английский текст с вопроса. А так же дайте более четкое описание того, что вы хотите получить

Comment: Вы все же на RuSO, а значит английский тут не уместен. По поводу вопроса - проверяйте по массиву/коллекции, методом `Contains`, либо LINQ `Any`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял что нужно получить...
То будет что-то вроде этого:

```
string str = (string)listBox1.Item[0];
label1.Text = new String(str.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());
```

Comment: Спасибо. С радостью бы проверил, но, почему-то, не смотря на то, что добавил в listbox строку, отладка накрывается, выдавая, что "ListBox было null". И что делать - не знаю.

Comment: потому, что код исполняется до того как ты выделил элемент в listBox1

Comment: Элемент добавляется с самого начала. А тот код, который ты дал, я на кнопку привязал. И, по сути, он должен высветить элемент в форме, а после того, как я его выберу и нажму кнопку, количество цифр высветится в Label.

Comment: добавляется не значит выделяется. Сейчас подправлю.